# Matlab: getting GUI handle value from a callback function when calling by another function

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am new to GUI programming for MATLAB, so my question relates to that.

Let's say that I create a GUI with GUIDE. In the creation function

```
MyGUI_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
```

I call another function,

```
SamplingRate_Callback(handles.SamplingRate, eventdata, handles)
```

defined as

```
function SamplingRate_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
```

SamplingRate_Callback sets a few variables,

```
handles.a = 1;
handles.b = 2;
handles.c = 3;
```

The `handles` structure updates correctly within the `SamplingRate_Callback` function. The problem I am having is that unless I change the function to

```
function handles = SamplingRate_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles),
```

I cannot return the data to the calling function, `MyGUI_OpeningFcn`. I have tried using `guidata(gcf, handles)` and `guidata(hObject, handles)`, but neither works.

Would you be able to shed some light on this problem?

Also, I am not sure when to use `guidata(gcf, handles)` vs. `guidata(hObject, handles)`.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

How do you call `SamplingRate_Callback` in your `MyGUI_OpeningFcn` function? It seems to me that you have not defined the return values, which would be `values` in this case.

The fix would be something like this:

```
function [handles] = SamplingRate_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
```

And then you would call `SamplingRate_Callback` from `MyGUI_OpeningFcn` like this:

```
handles = SamplingRate_Callback(handles.SamplingRate, eventdata, handles);
```

Comment: Hi nrz, thanks for your answer. Yes, that would work. I guess I don't understand why when SamplingRate_Callback is called directly by using its GUI element, you can simply save persistent handle values using guidata, but if you call the same function another way, guidata doesn't work. Does that make sense? Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean by data, you can use **getappdata** and **setappdata** to save and load data to/from the object itself (I generally use the axes that the data will be plotted on).